# I am not able to create groovy project

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, netbeans, groovy

I have used different approaches-

My system has jdk 1.8.1.

1. I tried installing Eclipse (oxygen and photon), Java programs are running fine but when I am installing groovy plugin from Help -> Install new software, it's not running.
2. Then I tried installing different IDE that is NetBeans, here also I am not able to create project.

Error:

```
Warning |
Unrecognized flag: non-interactive.
Error |
Specify an application name or use --inplace to create an application in the current directory
```

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you did in Eclipse, and what the exact problem is with setting up Groovy. Just saying "it's not running" is insufficient.

Comment: Also, since you are asking two distinct questions in the post above it would be appropriate to post your problem with Eclipse in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To create a Groovy/Grails project in NetBeans 8.2 you must first activate the **Groovy** plugin:

**Tools > Plugins > Installed >** select and check the **Groovy** plugin entry > Click **Activate**

After activation the **Active** icon for the **Groovy** entry should be a green circle with a white check mark:

[image: groovyActivation]

To use Grails:

- [Download the latest version of Grails](http://grails.org/download.html) and unzip it to a local directory.
- **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous >** select the **Groovy** tab.
- Click the **Browse...** button next to the **Grails Home** field and navigate to the directory containing Grails.

[image: addGrails]

After that you can create a **Groovy** project using the Project wizard:

**File > New Project... > Groovy**

[image: groovyProject]

Notes:

- With NetBeans 8.2 you only have to activate the Groovy plugin, but with [Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC1](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html) you must first install it: **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins > Groovy and Grails**
- See the NetBeans documentation [Introduction to Groovy](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/groovy-quickstart.html) for more information on using Groovy.
- See the NetBeans documentation [Introduction to the Grails Web Framework](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/grails-quickstart.html) for more information on using Grails.
- There are a couple of sample Groovy projects you can create with the Project Wizard:

**File > New Project... > Samples > Groovy**

[image: groovySamples]

Creating those projects would be useful for confirming that your environment is set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer..I have net beans 8.2 But I am not getting Groovy option, instead of that I am getting option "Groovy and Grails"..and under Tools- Options- Miscellaneous there is a option of Groovy Doc , in that I have put 'F:\office\groovy-2.4.15\html' and under Grails Home :, I have put 'F:\office\grails-3.3.6'  . When I created project I get this error - Problem: The project uses a class library called "swing-layout", but this class library was not found.
Solution: Click Resolve to open the Library Manager and create a new class library called "swing-layout".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `grails` application ? 
Best way to create a `grails` application is using a terminal console:

grails create-app --inplace

and after try to import in your IDE

see http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/create-app.html